# Excel - find duplicates in column A and move the value to column B

Tags: excel

If a value is found twice in column A, how do I put that value into the cell beside it in the next column?

Do I need vlookup?

Comment: So you want to end up with a list of duplicates and blanks?  Do you only want the first duplicate to be moved over, or do you want both?

Comment: Yes, duplicates and blanks, so if there's 4 Adam's in a row, I want Adam to copy over once and then 3 blanks

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the following formula into cell B1 and then copy the formula down (if I understood your question correctly):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,A1,"")
```